# How to add claims based on the fields from users table in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to add claim based on the name of department that is saved in users table in ASP.NET Core MVC? I have multiple users that belong to different departments.

Depending on their departments I want to create claims. Please guide me how to do this.

I know how to create and edit users or delete users claims using claims store but not the above problem.

Comment: Normally, we will add the claims after the user has successfully login in. Could you please tell me which authentication schema you have used now? Cookie, JWT or identity.   If you use cookie authentication, then you could get the user departments by using EF core and then create the claims and add it.

Comment: I'm using Identity user class. I have not used cookie authentication. Please guide how to use it

Comment: I will be really thankful to you if you guide me as I'm working on my university project. Just guide me how to use user's department which is saved in user's table to create claims and authorize user to access its respective department controller.

Comment: Any update?  Does my reply help you?

Comment: Yes sir. It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer, so that other folks could find the right solution more easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could create a custom claim factory which inherits `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`.

Then you could add the additional claims in the override GenerateClaimsAsync method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory:

```
using IdentityTestDemo.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityTestDemo
{
    public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _appliationDbContext;
        public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
            : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
            _appliationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        }

        protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
           //get the data from dbcontext
           var Iuser=   _appliationDbContext.Users.Where(x => x.EmailConfirmed == true).FirstOrDefault();

            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            //Get the data from EF core

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("EmailTest", Iuser.Email));
            return identity;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs：

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>(); ;
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

In the controller to get the claims:

```
        var result = User.FindFirst("EmailTest").Value;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Small hint for future user of this example. When you already use IdentityRole as well, for example for another claims based authorization where claims belongs to roles. Then you need to remeber to create `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>` instead `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>`. Cause then it would ignore those role claims